# Facebook - Android authorize app error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using facebook SDK 3.0.1 for android. I see at Facebook developers -> Insights -> Developer -> Activity & Errors some erros. I have an error that happens to 42% of my users : auth.androidauthorizeapp (error code 408 : The proxied app is not already installed).
Many of my users cannot get in to facebook. I believe that they fail at this exception.
I've read a bit about this problem and found that there could be some problems with the permission at the login.
I'm using facebook login button and I set to this button the permissions:

```
 LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(FacebookConfig.getInstance().getPermissions()));

  @Override
  public String[] getPermissions() {
    return new String[] {
      "user_about_me",
     // "offline_access",
      "friends_about_me",
      "user_photos",
      "friends_photos",
      "user_videos",
      "friends_videos",
      "read_stream",
      "friends_status",
      "user_photo_video_tags",
      "friends_photo_video_tags",
      "user_birthday",
      "friends_birthday",
    };
  }
```

What could that be? and how can I sove that problem? Thanks

Comment: I have the same error. I can see the failure rate of this error in my app is 44%. It's really quite high.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue with login to facebook. I was not using the facebook login button but using the session. i just removed if condition of !session.closed and its simply started working.

My code is :

```
  if (session == null ) {
       session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).setApplicationId(appId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
     }
```